# Vue/JS - Check if all values of two objects are null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have two objects with all the properties set to null. I want to execute a computed function to check whether all the values in both these objects are null. For one specific object I created the following:
`Object.values(endField.value).every(x => x === null)`

How can I do the same thing for two objects without being too repetitive in my code?

```
const startField = ref({ date: null, month: null, year: null })
const endField = ref({ date: null, month: null, year: null })

// If the properties of both objects are all null, isEmpty should be true.
const isEmpty = computed(() => {
    return Object.values(endField.value).every(x => x === null);
});
```

Comment: `return Object.values(endField.value).every(x => x === null)  && Object.values(startField.value).every(x => x === null);` ?

Comment: I tried that, however it returns false when one of the objets are not null. I need it to turn false when both of the objects are no longer null.

Comment: And what should it return if one of the objects is not null?

Comment: It should remain true if one of the objects is not null. It can only be false if both objects are not null.

Comment: Then use OR `||` instead of AND  `&&`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me:

If any property has a value, returns false, otherwise true.

```
        const startField = ref({ date: null, month: "Aug", year: null });
        const endField = ref({ date: null, month: null, year: null });

        const isEmpty = computed(() => {
            return (
                Object.values(endField.value).every((x) => x === null) ||
                Object.values(startField.value).every((x) => x === null)
            );
        });
```

Comment: @thelandog does the above change help?